# Flutter notifyListeners won't trigger rebuild

Tags: flutter, dart, mvvm

I have a flutter app that's using MVVM principles with ViewModel and ViewModelBuilders. I have a main page that has its own viewModel.

There is a process that runs in the background to update the data of that main page which contains a list of items. The way I do it is I have a Singleton that's registered when the app starts that does the background tasks. If the conditions are met, it's gonna send an event in a Stream. The ViewModel of that page is subscribed to the Stream, and upon receiving that even, it calls a function that's supposed to fetch the list of items and trigger a rebuild accordingly, with a call to notifyListeners.

My problem is that after the event is sent through the stream, I can see that it is consumed by the viewModel, I can see it retrieving the new list of item but the interface does not get rebuilt accordingly despite the items being fetched correctly.

Any idea what might make this not work? Thanks in advance !

Code:

The background tasks sending the event:

```
locator<ItemManager>().refreshStreamController.add(true);
```

When I build the main screen, I use `ViewModelBuilder.reactive` onModelReady it calls a function that subscribes to that stream controller like this:

```
refreshSubscription = locator<ItemManager>().refreshStreamController.stream.listen((event) async {
      if (event) {
        await fetchItems();
        log("Done fetching items");
        notifyListeners();
      }
    });
```

The log goes through, I can see the request to fetch items completing, but the interface doesn't get rebuilt.

Comment: please consider adding your code